# Extracting data in table using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-table

I'm scraping this [page](http://www.howtocallabroad.com/taiwan/) for my android app. I'd like to extract the data on the table of cities and area codes

Here's my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re

base_url = "http://www.howtocallabroad.com/taiwan/"
html_page = urllib2.urlopen(base_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)
codes = soup.select("#codes tbody > tr > td")
for area_code in codes:
    # print td city and area code
```

I'd like to know what function in python or in `BeautifulSoup` to get the values from `<td>value</td>`

Sorry just an android dev learning to write python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `findAll()`, along with a function which breaks up a list into chunks

```
>>> areatable = soup.find('table',{'id':'codes'})
>>> d = {}
>>> def chunks(l, n):
...     return [l[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(l), n)]
>>> dict(chunks([i.text for i in areatable.findAll('td')], 2))
{u'Chunan': u'36', u'Penghu': u'69', u'Wufeng': u'4', u'Fengyuan': u'4', u'Kaohsiung': u'7', u'Changhua': u'47', u'Pingtung': u'8', u'Keelung': u'2', u'Hsinying': u'66', u'Chungli': u'34', u'Suao': u'39', u'Yuanlin': u'48', u'Yungching': u'48', u'Panchiao': u'2', u'Taipei': u'2', u'Tainan': u'62', u'Peikang': u'5', u'Taichung': u'4', u'Yungho': u'2', u'Hsinchu': u'35', u'Tsoying': u'7', u'Hualien': u'38', u'Lukang': u'47', u'Talin': u'5', u'Chiaochi': u'39', u'Fengshan': u'7', u'Sanchung': u'2', u'Tungkang': u'88', u'Taoyuan': u'33', u'Hukou': u'36'}
```

### Explanation:

`.find()` finds a table with an id of `codes`. The `chunks` function is used to split up a list into [evenly sized chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python).

As `findAll` returns a list, we use chunks on the list to create something like:

```
[[u'Changhua', u'47'], [u'Keelung', u'2'], etc]
```

`i.text for i in...` is used to get the text of each `td` tag, otherwise the `<td>` and `</td>` would remain.

Finally, `dict()` is called to convert the list of lists into a dictionary, which you can use to access the country's area code.

Comment: this is what i'm looking for. well explained.

Comment: @zipc Thanks! And I figured out that I answered your previous BeautifulSoup question too! :p