# catch exception in BeautifulSoup.findAll function

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape this [afghanistan page](http://www.howtocallabroad.com/afghanistan/) by extracting the cities and area codes in the `table`. Now, When I try to scrape this [american-samoa page](http://www.howtocallabroad.com/american-samoa/), `findAll()` cannot find `<td>` which is true. How to catch this exception?

Here's my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup                                                                                                                                                                                                                
import urllib2                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
import re                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

url = "http://www.howtocallabroad.com/american-samoa"
html_page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)

areatable = soup.find('table',{'id':'codes'})
d = {}

def chunks(l, n):
    return [l[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(l), n)]

li = dict(chunks([i.text for i in areatable.findAll('td')], 2))
if li != []:
    print li

    for key in li:
            print key, ":", li[key]
else:
    print "list is empty"
```

This is the error i got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "extract_table.py", line 15, in <module>
    li = dict(chunks([i.text for i in areatable.findAll('td')], 2))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll'
```

I also tried this but doesn't work too

```
def gettdtag(tag):
    return "empty" if areatable.findAll(tag) is None else tag

all_td = gettdtag('td')
print all_td
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error says that `areatable` is `None`:

```
areatable = soup.find('table',{'id':'codes'})
#areatable = soup.find('table', id='codes')  # Also works

if areatable is None:
    print 'Something happened'
    # Exit out
```

Also, I'd use `find_all` instead of `findAll` and `get_text()` instead of `text`.

Comment: Dammit, I almost wrote the same answer.

Comment: In regards to using some functions instead of others, [that would](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16932131/1971805) be [my fault](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16916879/1971805) :P

Comment: @Haidro that would be my next todo, knowing the diff between `find_all` instead `findAll` learning python one step at a time =)

Comment: @zipc I think it's just a matter of `findAll` is part of version 3 of BeautifulSoup, and `find_all` is part of version 4. But `findAll` still works in 4. Take a look [here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names)